# how to get celerybeat cron tasks to run in docker container for django app?

Tags: django, docker, redis, docker-compose, celery

I'm trying to run celery beat tasks in my django/nuxt app
I have separate frontend and back end directories and I'm using docker-compose to build and run my app. (pycharm professional-mac-oS seria

I can run my tasks perfect without using docker containers locally but when I try to containerize to run, both celery and celery-beat wont stay running. I find the documentation is very poor online and even on celery's or dockers official documentation there's no mention of running celery & beat with docker
Can anyone tell me if my configuration is wrong or what I need to do in order for my app to accept the cronjobs in my settings.py?

I build my containers with `docker-compose up-d`
and run my app with `docker-compose exec django bash`

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

settings.py

```
    import os
    from configurations import Configuration, values
    from datetime import timedelta
    #print(os.environ)


    class Base(Configuration):

        DEBUG = values.BooleanValue(False)
        SECRET_KEY = '2pj=b#ywty7ojkv_gd#!$!vzywakop1azlxiqxrl^r50i(nf-^'
        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        DATABASES = values.DatabaseURLValue()
        ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

        INSTALLED_APPS = [
            "django.contrib.admin",
            "django.contrib.auth",
            "django.contrib.contenttypes",
            "django.contrib.sessions",
            "django.contrib.messages",
            "django.contrib.staticfiles",
            "rest_framework",
            "rest_framework.authtoken",
            "django_celery_results" ,
            "django_celery_beat" ,
            "corsheaders",
            "djoser",
            "accounts",
            "posts",
            "comments",
            "events",
        ]

        MIDDLEWARE = [
            "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
            "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
            "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
            "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
            "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
            "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
            "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
            "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
        ]

        ROOT_URLCONF = "spacenews.urls"
        TEMPLATES = [
            {
                "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
                "DIRS": [],
                "APP_DIRS": True,
                "OPTIONS": {
                    "context_processors": [
                        "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                        "django.template.context_processors.request",
                        "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                        "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                    ]
                },
            }
        ]

        # WSGI
        WSGI_APPLICATION = "spacenews.wsgi.application"
        # Password validators
        AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
            {
                "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator"  # noqa
            },
            {
                "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator"
            },
            {
                "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator"
            },
            {
                "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator"
            },
        ]
        AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"

        # Internationalization
        LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"
        TIME_ZONE = "UTC"
        USE_I18N = True
        USE_L10N = True
        USE_TZ = True

        # Static files

        STATIC_URL = "/static/"
        # REST
        REST_FRAMEWORK = {
            "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
                "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
                "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
                "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
            ),
            "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination",
            "PAGE_SIZE": 100,
        }


        CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/'
        CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/'
        #CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
        # use json format for everything
        CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
        CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
        CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
        CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'


        CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {


            'login_mb': {
                'task': 'events.tasks.login_mb',
                'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),

            } ,
            'mb_get_events': {
                'task': 'events.tasks.mb_get_events' ,
                'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10) ,

            } ,
        }



    class Development(Base):
        DEBUG = values.BooleanValue(True)
        CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
        ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "django","postgres","redis"]


    class Production(Base):
        pass


    class Testing(Base):
        pass
```

Dockerfile

```
    FROM python:3.6
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    #ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-client
    ADD . /app
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    EXPOSE 8000
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
  version: '2'

  services:

  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis

  api:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    environment:
       - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@db:5432/postgres
       - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://localhost:6379/
       - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND =redis://localhost:6379/
       - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=seekret
    volumes:
       - ./backend:/app

  celery:
    extends:
      service: api
    command:
      bash -c "cd spacenews && celery -A spacenews worker -B --loglevel=info"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  django:
    extends:
      service: api
    command: ./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- ./spacenews/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - celery
      - celery-beat

  celery-beat:
    extends:
      service: api

    command:
        bash -c "cd backend/spacenews && celery -A spacenews beat -B --loglevel=info"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - celery
  nuxt:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    environment:
      - API_URI=http://django:8000/api
    command: bash -c "npm install && npm run dev"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis

  volumes:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:
```

stacktrace celery container

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
        return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
    KeyError: 'data'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
        _main()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
        cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 496, in execute_from_commandline
        super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 275, in execute_from_commandline
        return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in handle_argv
        return self.execute(command, argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 420, in execute
        ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 221, in run_from_argv
        *self.parse_options(prog_name, argv, command))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 398, in parse_options
        self.parser = self.create_parser(prog_name, command)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 414, in create_parser
        self.add_arguments(parser)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 277, in add_arguments
        default=conf.worker_state_db,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 126, in __getattr__
        return self[k]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 429, in __getitem__
        return getitem(k)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 278, in __getitem__
        return mapping[_key]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 987, in __getitem__
        if key in self.data:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
        value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 141, in data
        return self.callback()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 924, in _finalize_pending_conf
        conf = self._conf = self._load_config()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 934, in _load_config
        self.loader.config_from_object(self._config_source)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 131, in config_from_object
        self._conf = force_mapping(obj)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 46, in force_mapping
        if isinstance(m, (LazyObject, LazySettings)):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 215, in inner
        self._setup()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/app/spacenews/spacenews/settings.py", line 7, in <module>
        class Base(Configuration):
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'spacenews.settings')



app = Celery('spacenews')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Comment: Can you please post your celery.py?

Comment: You have multiple beat workers. Only one beat scheduler should ever be used. `-B` is not recommended, drop it from your commands entirely. Instead have only one container do `celery -A spacenews beat` and then any other celery containers should be workers `celery -A spacenews worker`

Comment: @2ps celery.py posted

Comment: @systech still the same issue dropping –B

Answer (score 0):

You settings.py file does not look like it is valid for celery.  Usually settings files look like the following:

```
DEBUG = True

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/'
#CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
# use json format for everything
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'


CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {


    'login_mb': {
        'task': 'events.tasks.login_mb',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),

    } ,
    'mb_get_events': {
        'task': 'events.tasks.mb_get_events' ,
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10) ,

    } ,
}
```

without using objects like `Base`, `Production` or `Dev`.  If you want to use objects like you have, you have to do additional work to expose those as settings on the django settings object (that is being used to configure celery).

Alternatively, you can provide an instance of the class that contains that celery configuration to `config_from_object`.

Finally, please note that your the broker_url setting should be `BROKER_URL` and not `CELERY_BROKER_URL`.

Comment: my settings are fine. They work locally without docker. `CELERY_BROKER_URL` works fine too